# Passing HTML data into Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a web application from which I want to pass a text box value into a flask application.But, when I print out the request object in flask I do not get the data.Can you kindly help me out.Here are the codes:

Flask Server:

```
@app.route('/send_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def send_data():
    print request
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Operations with the data received 
    else:
    return jsonify(txt="Nothing received");
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="div_submit">
<form name="form_submit">
    <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="txt_query">

    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="send_query()">
</form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function send_query()
    {
        var qry=document.getElementById("txt_query").value;
        //alert(qry);
        var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var ajax=$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/send_data",
            data: JSON.stringify(qry),
            dataType: "json"

        }).done(function(data){
                alert("success");
            });
            ajax.fail(function(data){
                alert("fail");
            });


    }
```

Comment: Can someone kindly help me out ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting JSON data; set the content type to `application/json` and use the [`request.get_json()` method](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to load the data:

```
var ajax=$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/send_data",
    data: JSON.stringify({query: qry}),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
})
```

where the URL has to be meaningful; `0.0.0.0` is okay for servers (it means 'bind to all interfaces') but you are probably running this on localhost, so use that to begin with.

In your view use:

```
data = request.get_json()
query = data['query']
```

Comment: In the ajax call I am stating the method as POST. And when I print out the method name in the Flask server using request.method..I get it as POST.And request.method == "POST" is true.Its going inside the if statement.Everything is working..only If I do request.data I do not get anything.

Comment: @user2284140: sorry, I had indeed missed that. You want to post JSON, so use `requests.get_json()` and set the content type correctly.

Comment: If I do the changes you told. I get the following message from the server:
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2014 16:32:00] "OPTIONS /send_data HTTP/1.1" 500 
So, its a HTTP 500 message instead of 200.And when I do data = request.get_json(), its giving me a NoneType object. And the method has shifted from POST to OPTIONS

Comment: @user2284140: The AJAX code here doesn't use `OPTIONS` at all. That'd be something different entirely.

Comment: @user2284140: what does your log say went wrong? A 500 error is an exception in your code somewhere.

Comment: I get the following message from the server:
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2014 16:44:40] "OPTIONS /send_data HTTP/1.1" 200
I removed the 500 error message.But because of the Content type in the ajax, the method has changed to OPTIONS.If I remove the contenttype,the method shows as POST.

Comment: I tried removing the Content type. Then data = request.get_json() gives None type object.

Comment: With no proper content type you'd have to use `get_json(force=True)`. I'd not do that.

Comment: What browser is this? What does the network tab of the developer tools say was sent? The content type cannot possibly cause this unless something else *also* sends a `OPTIONS` request for JSON POSTs.

Comment: Finally it worked...by not setting the content type and making force=True in the get_json method... Thanks

Comment: @user2284140: it is strange that a) the `OPTIONS` request is sent whe n you use a JSON content type, and b) strange that the `OPTIONS` request results in an exception; Flask should handle those transparently (see the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule): *OPTIONS is implicitly added and handled by the standard request handling*.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a request in your flask app to receive the data:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object